Mediawiki, one wiki is a copy of another; I need to separate them
At my old company, I instigated and ran a wiki for many years (currently xxxx.wiki). I asked the host to create a copy once I left so my input would not be lost if my old company decided to ditch it. (It was copied successfully to wiki.xxxx.com). I modified the local settings.php for Sitename and Server.  My issue is that if I make changes on the old or new wiki, they're shown on the other, so they are still linked.
Which is the variable in local settings, like $wgDBname, $wgDBuser, etc. that will separate them? or is it another file?
MTIA

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
